# button position conflict in firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css

i am using input html button but its position is different in chrome and firefox, below is my code:

```
<tr style="float: left; margin-left: 24% !important; width: 100%;">
    <td>
        <div style="text-align: right;" class="txtNew">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="btn btn-booking unitRight size-btn-book-now mtm mbl" style="text-align: right;">
            <span style="float: left;">
                <button type="submit" onclick="return doSubmit();">Cancel</button></span>
            <span>
                <button type="submit" onclick="return doSubmit();">Next</button></span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

please visit http://www.travelinfi.com/VisaRequest.html  for above problem i face.

Comment: please solve this problem asap

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved by removing `width:50%` of the div class `btn btn-booking unitRight size-btn-book-now mtm mbl`